# Review Audit failed - is this really unclear?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this Review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/12055182). The question was closed as "unclear what you're asking".

However, I don't understand *why*. The question doesn't look that bad to me. The op provides some code and asks why it produces certain results. Nothing looks unclear to me. A little broad, perhaps, but even that is easily fixable.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Read the comments, they include hints as to why users chose that close option.  One or two may have voted to close as too broad as well.  The problem is that the code is a mess, and he's asking for ... something.  Or two somethings, I dunno.  I do agree that it's a poor review audit, tho.  Audits should be clear, not borderline like this.

Comment: I feel like I've seen this "The machine doesn't always generate valid audits" question several places before...

Comment: I don't recall if I choose unclear there myself but I think it is rather broad as the OP is asking for an explanation of a concept, not a specific problem. But I might have been some what heavy on the close vote there. In hindsight I should have skipped.

Comment: Looking at the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36137533/timeline) this has been used as an audit 6 times and this is the first failure.  I get confused reading the Q but not enough to vote either way.

Comment: @Will I could have lived with "too broad" - it's borderline imo, but something I would be willing to chalk up as my mistake. "Unclear what you're asking" just leaves me scratching my head.

Comment: @SamIam There are a bunch of similar questions ("I failed X audit, the system is broken/what happened") but I didn't see anything for this particular audit yet.

Comment: It was probably closed that way because of the last line: `Everything works fine but just need more understanding`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no shame in using "Skip"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was one of the people who closed this. Both too broad and unclear would have worked here, and it probably panned out 3-2 too broad <-> unclear here.

There are several red flags here in this Q that make it both too broad and unclear:

> Everything works fine but just need more understanding.

That says that OP wants a detailed explaination of what pointers are and why his code works, that's already too broad.

> Question: What do I receive when I call the function? Is what I
>   receive a Pointer to the String and if so why is it const?

Yet OP says his code works. We don't even have the full code and the context in which he uses it (the name of the func getData sounds heavily like embedded hardware) so we really can't know either way if OP's code really is working fine or if it's just UB and happens to work for some reason.

Too broad would have probably been better for this.

Comment: Note that 2-1-1-1 is another possibility.

Comment: Sorry, what does UB mean in your case, cause if I see here, I don't really have a clue why you are using that abbreviation ;) http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=UB

Comment: @Icepickle UB = [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: @T3H40 Thanks :) Is there a list of accepted SO abbreviations available here for the non-english speakers? There are many T(3/2)LA's that I really have to research in order to know what they mean in the meta posts :D